SQL-оператор || не может работать со несколькими операторами ->>
Работал над формированием из выборочных значений json строки c адресом посредством sql-запроса (postgresql).
Пример json:
[
    {"addr_type": 1, "city": "Рязань", "flat": "", "house": "д 123", "region": "", "street": "ул Ленина", "zip_code": "998877", "country": "РФ"},
    {"addr_type": 2, "city": "Москва", "flat": "кв 123", "house": "д 123", "region": "", "street": "ул Пушкина", "zip_code": "112233", "country": "РФ"}
]

Пример строки:
112233, Москва, ул Пушкина

Столкнулся с тем, что формирование строки через select с операторами || не работает напрямую с несколькими объектами из json, которые получаются через операторы ->>.
Неработающий запрос:
select
    (select ja->>'zip_code' || ', ' || ja->>'city' || ', ' || ja->>'street'
    from json_array_elements(v.addr) as ja
    where ja->>'addr_type' = '2'
    )::varchar as "ADDR"
from public.addr_info as v;

json_array_elements распаковывает нужный json, и далее я ожидаю с помощью ->> получить значения в типе text по нужным ключам, как это заявлено в документации.
Работает это только с одним ->>. При добавлении в select новых операторов возникает ошибка:

SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: operator does not exist: text ->> unknown.
No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.

Приведение получаемых элементов через ::text не помогает:
select ja->>'zip_code'::text || ', ' || ja->>'city'::text || ', ' || ja->>'street'::text


SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: operator does not exist: text ->> text.
No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.

Если сделать дополнительный select, в котором предварительно получить из json нужные значения, то потом можно успешно создать строку:
select
    (select ja.zip_code || ', ' || ja.city || ', ' || ja.street
    from (select
            vv->>'zip_code' as "zip_code",
            vv->>'city' as "city",
            vv->>'street' as "street"
            from json_array_elements(v.addr) as vv
            where vv->>'addr_type' = '2') as ja
    )::varchar as "ADDR"
from public.addr_info as v;

Либо помогает использование функции concat_ws:
select
    (select concat_ws(', ', ja->>'zip_code', ja->>'city', ja->>'street')
    from json_array_elements(v.addr) as ja
    where ja->>'addr_type' = '2'
    )::varchar as "ADDR"
from public.addr_info as v;

Есть ли какое-то объяснение, почему даже при принудительном приведении к text значений из json строка не может быть конкатенирована через ||, но при этом нормально собирается иными методами?

Ну а если обернуть каждый оператор в скобки, тем самым указав приоритет операции?

Да, мне тоже кажется нужно со скобками поиграться попробовать.

@u_mulder да, спасибо за наводку - со скобками запрос выполняется! Видимо без них преобразование объектов в text оператором ->> осуществляется позже, чем происходит конкатенация строк
